# pomp package COVID SEIR model least squares errors traceback

Tags: r, least-squares, traceback

I try to model a SEIR for UK to evaluate the implemented containment measures and found some code with the pomp package here: https://kingaa.github.io/clim-dis/parest/parest.html
I tried to transfer this to my case which adds one stage (E) and three more variables. In the end i want to do a least squared estimation to find the optimal beta.
Data_UK_beta0 consists of the variable date (int from 0 to 165) and new_cases (from John Hopkins University dataset).

```
Data_UK_pomp_beta0 <- pomp(
  data= Data_UK_beta0,
  times ="date", t0=0,
  skeleton = vectorfield(
    Csnippet("
      DS=-beta1*S*I/N;
      DE= beta1*S*I/N-delta1*E;
      DI=delta1*E-(gamma1+eta1)*I;
      DR=gamma1*I;")),
  rinit = Csnippet("
      S=S_0;
      E=E_0;
      I=I_0;
      R=N-S_0-E_0-I_0;"),
  statenames = c("S","E","I","R"),
  paramnames = c("beta1","delta1","gamma1","eta1","N","S_0","E_0","I_0")) 


sse_UK_beta0 <- function (params) {
  x <- trajectory(Data_UK_pomp_beta0,params=params)
  discrep <- x["I",,]-obs(Data_UK_pomp_beta0)
  sum(discrep^2)
}


install.packages("apricom")
library(apricom)

beta_reg <- function (beta0) {
  params <- c(beta1=beta0, delta1=1/5.1, gamma1=1, eta1=0.012649, N=67886004, S_0=67886004, E_0=5, I_0=2)
  sse(params)
}


beta0 <- seq(from=1,to=40,by=1)
SSE <- sapply(beta0, beta_reg)
```

got the following error traceback (unfortunately in german, but i guess the message should be clear :)

```
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'as.matrix': Argument "dataset" fehlt (ohne Standardwert) 
7.
h(simpleError(msg, call)) 
6.
.handleSimpleError(function (cond) 
.Internal(C_tryCatchHelper(addr, 1L, cond)), "Argument \"dataset\" fehlt (ohne Standardwert)", 
    base::quote(as.matrix(dataset))) 
5.
as.matrix(dataset) 
4.
sse(params) 
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
1.
sapply(beta0, beta_reg)
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sse` function you've imported from `apricom` has nothing (as far as I can see) to do with this problem. (This also doesn't have anything to do with C(++) code compilation, so the [compiler-errors] tag in your question is a little misleading.)

You haven't given us a way to get your `Data_UK_beta0` data set so I can't reproduce this, but I assume that you actually want something like:

```r
beta_reg <- function (beta0) {
    params <- c(beta1=beta0, delta1=1/5.1, gamma1=1, 
                eta1=0.012649, N=67886004, S_0=67886004, E_0=5, I_0=2)
    sse_UK_beta0(params)
}
beta0 <- seq(from=1,to=40,by=1)
SSE <- sapply(beta0, beta_reg)
```

You should also be aware that are a bunch of other potentially tricky issues in what you're doing. One that jumps out is that you are likely comparing the *prevalence* of infection in the modeling (the current number in the `I` compartment) to *case report* data, which is a (lagged, biased, imperfect) measure of the *incidence* of disease, i.e. the number of new cases per unit time ...

Comment: thank you, it worked! You are totally right about the difficulty of comparing the two variables. It would be better to calculate the actual infected individuals ((= total cases - total deaths - recovered)for every day) out of the "real data". Unfortunately UK doesn't provide the data of recovered individuals which would probably also be biased. Be happy to hear a solution for that but so far couldn't find anything.

Comment: you would be closer comparing new cases to `delta*E`

Comment: Good idea, thanks! implemented that like this: 
`sse_UK_beta0 <- function (params) {
  x <- trajectory(Data_UK_pomp_beta0,params=params)
  discrep <- x["E",,]*delta1-obs(Data_UK_pomp_beta0)
  sum(discrep^2)
}`
Even though it lead to worse results and therefore probably more realistic ones :)